# How to create callback URL in ordering certificates from IBM certificate manager?

Tags: dns, ibm-cloud, ibm-certificate-manager

I needs to order certificate in IBM certificate manager from another dns provider(google domains).In this process, how to create callback url to validate the domain.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint for a Callback URL notifications channel can be any server capable of receiving network requests where you implement code that will process the events sent to it and respond according to the spec.

You can also use IBM Cloud Function actions to more easily set it up instead.

You should read through the documentation([1](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/certificate-manager?topic=certificate-manager-ordering-certificates#other_provider), [2](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/certificate-manager?topic=certificate-manager-configuring-notifications#setup-callback)) to learn what is expected in order to validate domain ownership, and how to configure your Callback URL notifications channel.

You can then follow the steps [mentioned in this GitHub repository](https://github.com/ibm-cloud-security/certificate-manager-domain-validation-cloud-function-sample/tree/master/CloudflareSample) to create a Cloud Function that validates domain ownership for CloudFlare - you should be able to update the sample code to work with a DNS provider of your choice.